# Break text on multiple lines inside JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, semantic-ui

Having this component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Popup } from "semantic-ui-react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const value = "TEST";
  return (
    <Popup
      content={`This is the data: ${value}`}
      on="click"
      pinned
      trigger={<div>{value}</div>}
    />
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I want to show the `content` data on multiple lines but is seems to not work.

Tried so far:

```
content={`This{"\n"}is the data: ${value}`}
content={`This \n is the data: ${value}`}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using a `<br>` element instead of `\n`

Comment: tried like content={`This<br/>is the  data: ${value}`}. still not working

Comment: You can directly pass jsx instead of string in that way you can modify your statement

Answer (score -1):

Seems like this is an old issue.

Answered here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5575

> Solved using html instead of content and `<br />` as separator.